# Typescript Documentation on Class Decorator - function returning "class extends constructor {}"

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator, class-decorator

So, I am trying to build understanding about Typescript Decorators and I have been stuck on the example given about Class decorators. The example given shows how to form class decorator through function(){}.

```
  function classDecorator<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T){
        return class extends constructor {
            newProperty = "new property";
            hello = "override";
        }
    }    

    @classDecorator
    class Greeter {
        property = "property";
        hello: string;
        constructor(m: string) {
            this.hello = m;
        }
    }    

    console.log(new Greeter("world"));
```

What is the:

```
return class extends constructor {
    newProperty = "new property";
    hello = "override";
}
```

How can a function returning a "class" keyword that extends a parameter (called "construct")? I am so confused.

Here is link to original source (just scroll to the middle section on class decorator): https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at the full declaration of the decorator:

```
function classDecorator<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T) {
    return class extends constructor {
        newProperty = "new property";
        hello = "override";
    }
}
```

It's pretty gnarly, but here's what's going on.

The type of `constructor` is something that satisfies the `T` type parameter.

This type parameter `T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}` applies to any object that has a constructor that takes any number of arguments of any type (i.e., pretty much anything).

What this decorator does is instead of returning the `constructor` that is passed in, a different class is returned.

Note that the syntax `return class { ... }` is a way to return an anonymous class from a function, much like `return function() { ... }` returns an anonumous function.

And `class extends constructor` means that the anonymous class inherits all of `constructor`'s methods and properties (constructor is the class being decorated).

Comment: Thx sir. And so the use of the "constructor" as parameter name does not violate any rule (that will result to error) does it? And i can also use any other words for the parameter, yes? (cheers, ur respond helps!)

Comment: Anyway, thx for ur respond again. I think again, i may just need to learn more with the basics. =) *cheers,

Comment: Yes, you can use `constructor` as a parameter name or as a variable name in this context.

Answer (score 0):

As to "**class extends**", It is ES6 javascript syntax :
["class expression"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class)

you can test this code in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/):

```
class Car {
    constructor(brand) {
    this.carname = brand;
  }
  present() {
    return 'I have a ' + this.carname;
  }
}

const Model = class extends Car {
  constructor(brand, mod) {
    super(brand);
    this.model = mod;
  }
  show() {
    return this.present() + ', it is a ' + this.model;
  }
}

console.log(new Model("Ford", "Mustang").show());
```

---result:
"Running fiddle"
"I have a Ford, it is a Mustang"